# Why it is throwing Exception for the second query?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am getting errors when I tried to update some information. The errors are as follow:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.app.dao.RolesDAO.getUserRoleByUserID(RolesDAO.java:42)
    at com.app.business.UserRolesBusiness.updateInformation(UserRolesBusiness.java:21)
    at com.app.business.UserRolesBusiness.main(UserRolesBusiness.java:29)
```

After debugging, I saw that the business layer works finely to retrieve the userID. But it failed to update the information later. My code implementation are like the following:

Business layer implementation:

```
public void updateInformation(String userName, String roleName) {

    Users user = dao1.getUserInfo(userName);
    String userIDString = Integer.toString(...);

    Roles updateRole = dao2.getUserRoleByUserID(userIDString);
    updateRole.setRole(roleName);
    r.updateRole(updateRole);

}
```

DAO layer implementation:

getUserInfo Method:

```
.....
user = ... query.list().get(0);
....
```

getUserRoleByUserID method:

```
....
role = ... query.list().get(0);
....
```

What is the reason of throwing the exception "IndexOutOfBoundsException" and how to solve the problem. It successfully executed for the first query but not executing for the second query. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `query.list().get(0)` twice without checking the size of the list. If one of them is empty, the result will get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. Call the `isEmpty()` method or verify that the `size()` is greater than zero before attempting to fetch the first list element.